# VC++ compiler ignores an overloaded function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading, visual-c++-2008

Here is my code (simplified):

```
//wrapper.h
#include <play3d.h>
class wrapper
{
private:
    soundengine *soundEngine;
public:
    sound *playSound3D(source *source, D3DXVECTOR3 pos, bool loop=false);
};

//wrapper.cpp
sound *wrapper::playSound3D(source *source, D3DXVECTOR3 pos, bool loop)
{
    return soundEngine->play3D(source, pos, loop);
};
```

And here is my full code (as requested).  It uses the irrKlang sound engine:

```
//irrKlang.h
virtual ISound* play3D(ISoundSource* source, vec3df pos,
    bool playLooped = false, 
    bool startPaused = false, 
    bool track = false,
    bool enableSoundEffects = false) = 0;//the version i want

virtual ISound* play3D(const char* soundFileName, vec3df pos,
    bool playLooped = false, 
    bool startPaused = false,
    bool track = false, 
    E_STREAM_MODE streamMode = ESM_AUTO_DETECT,
    bool enableSoundEffects = false) = 0;//the version vc++ finds


//fsCore.h
#include <irrklang.h>
class fsEngine
{
private:
    static fsEngine *instance;
    static fsBool exists;
    irrklang::ISoundEngine *soundEngine;
    fsEngine();
    ~fsEngine();
public:
    static fsEngine *getInstance()
    {
        if (!exists)
        {
            instance = new fsEngine();
            exists = true;
            return instance;
        }
        else
        {
            return instance;
        }
    };
    void release()
    {
        exists = false;
        delete instance;
        soundEngine->drop();
    };
public:
    irrklang::ISoundSource *loadSound(fsString filename);
    irrklang::ISoundSource *cloneSound(irrklang::ISoundSource *source, fsString alias=NULL);
    irrklang::ISound *playSound2D(irrklang::ISoundSource *source, fsBool loop=false);
    irrklang::ISound *playSound3D(irrklang::ISoundSource *source, D3DXVECTOR3 soundpos, fsBool loop=false);
};


//fsCore.cpp
#include "fsCore.h"
irrklang::ISound *fsEngine::playSound3D(irrklang::ISoundSource *source, D3DXVECTOR3 soundpos, bool loop)
{
    return soundEngine->play3D(source, soundpos, loop);
};
```

I am getting a [C2664 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from nowhere.

```
1>c:\users\...\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\core\fscore.cpp(20) : error C2664: 'irrklang::ISound *irrklang::ISoundEngine::play3D(const char *,irrklang::vec3df,bool,bool,bool,irrklang::E_STREAM_MODE,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'irrklang::ISoundSource *' to 'const char *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Play3D() has two definitions: one that accepts a `'const char *'` as argument 1, and another that accepts `'source *'` as argument 1.  Intellisense points out both definitions, but I can't get the VC++ 2008 express compiler to recognize the version I want.  What do I change?

Comment: Are the other arguments you pass to the function of the correct type? Please post the _complete_ and _unedited_ error messages.

Comment: Suggest you post the definitions of your two play3D methods.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg unedited code and error added.

Comment: How does `D3DXVECTOR3` relate to `vec3df`? Not obvious that these types are compatible.

Comment: No problem there.  They are both `struct`s with 3 float values.  The error is from the first argument.

Comment: But are they the same struct? I mean one is a typedef for the other?

Comment: My guess from seeing the overloaded virtual functions is that the methods are hiding your virtual methods from base class.

Comment: @john no typedef, but vc++ has no problem converting them.

Comment: @Catsup That seems unlikely considering that they are unrelated types written by different authors. Try rewriting your code with a manual conversion.

Comment: @john damn.  the errors started counting at 0.  you were right.  +1 on all your comments once i get enough rep xD.

Comment: @Catsup -- did it for you

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code, both identified in the comments.

#### #1, from @john:

```
virtual ISound* play3D(ISoundSource* source,
    vec3df pos,
    bool playLooped = false, 
    bool startPaused = false, 
    bool track = false,
    bool enableSoundEffects = false) = 0;

irrklang::ISound *fsEngine::playSound3D(irrklang::ISoundSource *source,
                                        D3DXVECTOR3 soundpos, bool loop)
{
    return soundEngine->play3D(source, soundpos, loop);
}
```

The caller passes a `D3DXVECTOR3`, but the callee expects a `vec3df`. These are different types, and there's no implicit conversion between them, so the compiler will give you *some* sort of error. The particular error it gives you might be a little misleading in this case.

(It doesn't matter that both classes are the same size and have the same data members in the same order. C++ [only treats two types as equal if they *are* equal,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system) regardless of [how they happen to be implemented internally.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system))

#### #2, from @Named:

Even if `D3DXVECTOR3` and `vec3df` are typedefs for the exact same type, you've got another problem. Your two virtual methods have the same name, so they are overloads; and because of how function over-*loading* interacts with virtual over-*riding*, the child class's overload actually hides the parent's version. Example:

```
struct X; struct Base                  { virtual void foo(X *); };
struct Y; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void foo(Y *); };

void f(Derived *d, X *x) { d->foo(x); }


% clang++ -Wall test.cc
test.cc:2:59: warning: 'Derived::foo' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    struct Y; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void foo(Y *); };
                                                          ^
test.cc:1:59: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'Base::foo' declared here
    struct X; struct Base                  { virtual void foo(X *); };
                                                          ^
test.cc:4:39: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Y *' with an lvalue of type 'X *'
    void f(Derived *d, X *x) { d->foo(x); }
                                      ^
test.cc:2:66: note: passing argument to parameter here
    struct Y; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void foo(Y *); };
                                                                 ^
```

One way to fix this is with a `using` directive:

```
struct X; struct Base                  { virtual void foo(X *); };
struct Y; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void foo(Y *); using Base::foo; };

void f(Derived *d, X *x) { d->foo(x); }
```

This re-adds `Base::foo` to the candidate list when we're looking up `foo` in contexts involving `Derived`. However, a *much much* better solution is to use unique identifiers for unique functionalities:

```
struct X; struct Base                  { virtual void foox(X *); };
struct Y; struct Derived : public Base { virtual void fooy(Y *); };

void f(Derived *d, X *x) { d->foox(x); }
```

Here there's no confusion about which function you meant to call — no confusion on the compiler's part, *and* no confusion on the human reader's part. Function overloading in C++ is a tool designed to solve a very specific problem. [If you don't have that problem, don't use that tool!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibiotic_resistance)

Comment: Java method overloading/overriding has always been a lot easier for me to understand.